# "items list" or "item list"

Tags: c++, naming-conventions

English is not my native language and I can't understand how to write the specified samples right.
When you say something what aggregates plural object such as "collection of stamps" you can say alternatively: "stamps collection", am I right? If you will say "stamp collection" it will mean some "collection" which is a single "stamp".

But often I see classes with names like "ItemList" - doesn't it mean that such class is a list which is an item of something else?
Such sample is more flaring:

```
class ItemList: List<Item>
```

Isn't it have to be so?:

```
class ItemsList: List<Item>
```

Why is it rarely written so? Or is it some programming languages naming convention? Or just proper english sentences? :)

Comment: @WeaselFox: Some people have a deep-seated, healthy curiosity about the world around them, and are keen to learn. If you are not one of these people, then you're free to ignore this question.

Comment: I am no native english speaker as well, so take my comment with a grain of salt. I'd prefer `ItemList` over `ItemsList`, as the term `List` already contains the notion of multiple contained objects.

Comment: Possibly because `Item` is the name of the class being stored in the list.

Comment: Slav, in reality, `stamp collection` is correct not `stamps collection` that's why `ItemList` is used also.

Comment: In English, we're always turning nouns into adjectives that modify other nouns, and we use the singular noun when we do. "Sweet shop", "candy store", "duck pond", "prawn sandwich", "piano tuner". That's why a collection of stamps is called a "stamp collection" in English. "Stamp collection" would never mean specifically a collection of one stamp, except perhaps as a humorous device (Terry Pratchett wrote a book that mentioned a Plague of Frog). Or very pedantically some "stamp collection" might *happen* to contain only one stamp, but you usually wouldn't call that a collection in English.

Comment: It's amazing that anyone learns English as anything other than a first language.  To me, 'ItemList' is a list of items, 'ItemsList' is a bill of materials and 'ItemsLists' is a term with too many 's' that sounds like an American import.  +1 to Steve for TP reference.

Comment: @MartinJames: Why is it "amazing"?

Comment: Irrelevant, but related: A German comedian once claimed that Semmelknödel (bread dumplings) should properly be referred to as Semmelnknödeln (breadS dumplings) when they are made out of more than one bread. Google for Semmelnknödeln if you speak German.

Comment: This is a good question, but it should be asked on ELU.SE, not here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - becasue their are so many similare worms with diferent moanings.

Comment: @wolfgang - interesting story, but I'm really hungry now and I don't care about the spelling, as long as it's tasty! I looked them up & they seem to be Bavarian. When I go to Germany, it's Baden-Württemberg, but I could ask about dumplings next time..

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**In English, a "collection of stamps" is a "stamp collection".** (At best, "stamps collection" would be understood).

**In programming,** I'm not entirely sure why, but **we<sup>1</sup> *do* sometimes use the form "StampsCollection"**.

It may be because we try to use more precise and logical lingo than traditional English provides; we start with the name "Item", pluralise it to "Items", *then* be precise by stating that our collection of "Items" is a "List" rather than an "Array" or some other implementation.

You're likely to see both variants, though, and it doesn't really matter.

Certainly, neither in English nor in programming would `ItemsList` imply a list of collections of `Items`, at least not to most people.

---

<sup>1</sup> ... for some value of "we". Naming choices are, of course, down to personal preference. However, I've personally seen this as a tendency.

Comment: "we do tend to use the form "stamps collection" instead" - FWIW, I don't. I'd call it either `stampCollection` or `stamps`. Personally I don't recall seeing `stampsCollection` much, but that might just be a quirk of the dialect (both English and programming-language) of the colleagues I've had.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I suppose there's no way to make an answer either way there. We're certainly more likely to see it in programming than in real English.

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong to read what you wrote this way, but I read "tend to do X" as meaning, "do X more often than not X". Which I think I disagree with in this case, but obviously I can't say whether *you've* observed that tendency in the code you've read :-) Even worse, one of the problems lexicographers face, and that we face here, is distinguishing variant usage from usage that is intentional at time of writing, but "incorrect".

Comment: @SteveJessop: You read it right. I guess I'm abusing the word "we".

Comment: OK, we're certainly agreed that it happens, and that you have to be able to read both conventions.

Comment: how about e.g. "names of countries"? 1. `countryNames` could mean different names for each country (US, USA, the United States of America, America, States etc), 2. `countriesNames` sound a bit verbose but it's what I mean here probably (I've got 3 countries and I put 3 names of them in a collection), 3. `countryNameList` / `countryNameCollection` sounds odd but may be the correct one?

Comment: @andrusieczko: I'm not sure you could make it unambiguous anyway, so just pick one and let the documentation describe the variable's meaning. (BTW, I'm curious as to why you picked the USA as your example, since you're a Pole living in Singapore and I'm a Pole living in the UK and Steve lives in the UK lol)

Comment: haha, 1. I didn't check where you guys are from, 2. wanted to make a Polish example (Polska, Rzeczpospolita Polska, Poland, Republic of Poland), then Singaporean (Republic of Singapore, Singapore, 新加坡, Singapura, சிங்கப்பூர) but didn't have a good one in one language, and the USA was just a perfect one :) and I asked just out of curiosity, the real variable name is `airlineNameList` but country name gave me a better example ;)

Answer (score 11):

I find `ItemList` much more descriptive. It is a `list` of objects of type `Item`.

On the other hand, if you had a collection of `Item` objects, you could call it `Items`, and `ItemsList` would designate a `list` of collections.

Comment: I would not expect `ItemsList` to be a list of collections.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit me neither. But say someone else did `typedef std::vector<Item> Items`. How would you call `std::list<Items>`?

Comment: I would `typedef Items ItemsArray` and then `typedef std::list<ItemsArray> ItemsArraysList`, whilst stabbing the original author in the face

Comment: It occurs to me also that you could also get to `itemsList` via some form of Hungarian notation. The object is your `items`, and its type is `List`. Not very nice, but nevertheless half-assed Hungarian notations aren't that unusual.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Items: List<Item>
```

And more readable, in general I do a typedef

```
// C++98
typedef List<Item> Items;

// since C++11 you can write it also this way, and I prefer this:
using Items = List<Item>;
```

It is **often** good practice (clean code) to think about a more specialized class that hides the List. **"Prefer composition by aggregation over inheritance"** is common idiom in OOP (quoting Sutter/Alexandrescu: C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices)

Encapsulation of a collection is most of the time a good practice which lowers the complexity of calling code:

```
class Encapsulation
{
    Items m_items;
    public: 
    void AddItem(const Item&);
    void RemoveAllItems();
    // ... all the functions about managing the List that would be otherwise boilerplate code spread all over your codebase
}
```